# Required input fields turn red after clear on submit. Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firefox, axios

I have a form which calls a redux action and then clears the input fields if the post was successful . The issue seems to be after the input fields are cleared on a successful post the input fields turn red.

**redux action function**

```
postActionFunction = (data, clearDataFunction) => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .post(`/endpoint`, data)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('success');
    })
    .then(() => {
      clearDataFunction();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('error');
    });
};
```

**form submit function**

```
 onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { inputData } = this.state;
  // below function is the redux action
    this.props.postCategories(inputData, this.clearDataFunction);
  }

 clearDataFunction() {
    this.setState({ inputData: '' });
  }
```

**Edit : 
This seems to happen only with Firefox developer's edition**

Comment: That should depend on your validation. show us the validation related code ..

Comment: The validation happens in the backend and it doesn't return anything that is linked into the input fields .

Comment: The html might help

Comment: So the fields turn red on Firefox developer's edition and the word `success` is printed to the console at the same time? Assuming `success` should be a string and it's just a typo

Comment: Yes the fields become empty, the 'success' message is printed in console. But the fields turn red.

Comment: I think html turns required fields red as soon as submit is hit. I refresh the page to get rid of it

Comment: Had the same problem, it's only in firefox